# using wp_get_attachment_image_src in foreach loop

Tags: wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I have 10 images added to a post via Advanced Custom Fields, they're named from 1 to 10 e.g 'image_*', ACF is set to return the ID.

I'm trying to get the full size image URL of each image in the loop and use it as a `href` attribute to open a full size popup of the image, however I don't understand how wp_get_attachment_image_src works.

Since I am unable to use Advanced Custom Field's Repeater, this is the loop i'm using to get an array of the images with a custom image size of `scaled`, it works fine to generate the responsive image markup that I need:

```
// args    

$sizeHuge = 'scaled'; // scaled image  
$images = array(); // img array

for($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
        $img = get_field('image_' . $x);
   if($img) {
        $images[] = $img; 
   } else {
        break;
   }
 }


<?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>

    <a href="" class="open-viewer">

        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $sizeHuge ); ?>

    </a>

<?php } ?>
```

I need to set the `href` attribute of the parent `a` element with the URL of the image. This is what I have tried with wp_get_attachment_image_src, it doesn't work, it sets every `href` with `image_10`'s URL.

```
// args

$sizeFull = 'full'; // full size image
$sizeHuge = 'scaled'; // scaled image  
$images = array(); // img array

for($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
        $img = get_field('image_' . $x);
        $image_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img, $sizeFull);
        $link = $image_array[0];                
   if($img) {
        $images[] = $img; 
   } else {
        break;
   }
 }


<?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="open-viewer">

        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $sizeHuge ); ?>

    </a>

<?php } ?>
```

**My question is: How can I set the `href` of `a.open-viewer` with the correct URL?, and secondly, why does my code fail? (debug is switched on but no errors appear).**

I realise I've horribly misunderstood something here, I'm a PHP novice so any advice about my approach would be appreciated.

Comment: did you  added image in a repeater field or created 10 different field with different id ?

Comment: @Balwant No, I'm unable to use the Repeater extension so I created ten images with different ID's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first block, in your loop, you're setting the value of `$link` to the value of `$image_array[0]`, but you're overwriting it each time. You want `array_push` here.

```
$images = array();
for($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
  $img = get_field('image_' . $x);
  $image_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img, $sizeFull);       

  if($image_array && $image_array[0]) {
    array_push($images, 
        array(
           src => $image_array[0],
           id => $img
        )
    ); 
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

Now, when you loop over it the second array, you can just do:

```
<?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>
   <a href="<?php echo $image['src']; ?>" class="open-viewer">
      <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image['id'], $sizeHuge ); ?>
   </a>
<?php } ?>
```

And the value of `href` should be the image URL.

Comment: As an aside `$sizeHuge` and `$sizeFull` would be more readable (and more  semantically correct) as constants. `const SIZE_FULL = "full";` etc

Comment: Thank you, this now creates the `a` tag perfectly, but the `<img>` markup is not being created at all, I suspect this is related to not using both `wp_get_attachment_image` and `wp_get_attachment_image_src` together? You've given me a great starting point here, thank you for your help

Comment: @DavidAlsbright - See updated answer, `wp_get_attachment_image` takes the image attachment ID as its first parameter, which you appear to be getting from `get_field`. Updated code should give you access to the ID from the original loop.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the updated/corrected code which will work for you:

```
 <?php

   // args

    $sizeFull = 'full'; // full size image
    $sizeHuge = 'scaled'; // scaled image  
    $images = array(); // img array

    for($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
            $img = get_field('image_' . $x);
       if($img) {
            $images[] = $img; 
       } else {
            break;
       }
     }


    <?php foreach($images as $image) { 
          $image_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, $sizeFull);
          $link = $image_array[0];  
         ?>

        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="open-viewer">

            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $sizeHuge ); ?>
            // or Rather than calling above function, why don't you write <img> tag as you already have image url ? Like:
            <img src="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="">

        </a>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: If, for any reason, `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` doesn't find an attachment, it returns false. This code will fail when trying to access an array index of a boolean in that scenario.